# Simple thing, how to store variables into an array?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have this function, I need to store some values in an array, I need to create an array variable and store them here.

I have this function:

```
function loadFriends()
{
    //get array of friends
    FB.api('/me/friends?fields=name,first_name,gender', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var divContainer=$('.facebook-friends');
        var testdiv = document.getElementById("test");

for(var i=0; i<response.data.length; i++){
    if(response.data[i].gender == 'male'){
         testdiv.innerHTML += response.data[i].id + '<br />';
    }
}
```

I need to store all values of `response.data[i].id` in an array, as an array.
I need something like `var array = [1,2,3,4]` where 1,2,3,4 are the `response.data[i].id`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to store all values of response.data[i].id in an array

Use `push`:

```
var  arr = []; // Creates an empty array literal.

for(var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++){
        arr.push(response.data[i].id);
}
```

[**Read about `push` at MDN site**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)